# Google Analytics Content Grouping using Extraction

Tags: google-analytics

Given URLs of the format:

```
/dashboard/app/Minecraft/info
/dashboard/app/Minecraft/players
/dashboard/app/Diablo/players
```

When I create a content group with extraction RegEx:

`/app/(.*?)/`

I see would expect to see Minecraft & Diablo as extracted values - but no extracted apps names are being shown - I get 1 row, which is **(not set)**

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related. may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

The regex was correct, but I was under the impression it would apply to historical data, looking at data coming in, the apps are being collected correctly.